Getting the DateRange in .aspx and .aspx.cs files
I'm trying to build on both front-end and back-end a date-range display such that when a user selects between two dates, it filters information between those two points. So far, I am having issues with just the first portion of the front end and managed to come up with this based on some examples I saw online
    <details>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-auto">
                <asp:Repeater ID="rFilterDateStarts" RunAt="Server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <label class="form-label">Date From:</label>
                        <asp:TextBox AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtDateStart" RunAt="Server" TextMode="Date" />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary badge rounded-pill text-body-emphasis"><%# Eval("created_date", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %></button>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>

        <div class="col-auto">
            <asp:Repeater ID="rFilterDateEnds" RunAt="Server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <label class="form-label">Date To:</label>
                    <asp:TextBox AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtDateEnds" RunAt="Server" TextMode="Date" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary badge rounded-pill text-body-emphasis"><%# Eval("created_date", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %></button>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </div>
</details>

I am very new to C# and want to know if this is correct or I'm going about things in the wrong direction.
I tried to follow the examples for the C# and SQl from the block codes I found online.
<div class='container'>
    <div class="row">
        From:<asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" class="form-control date-input" ReadOnly="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        To:<asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" runat="server" class="form-control date-input" ReadOnly="true" />
    </div>
    <hr />
    <asp:GridView ID="gvEmployees" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-responsive table-bordered">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <asp:Button Text="Filter" runat="server" OnClick="OnFilter" />
</div>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        gvEmployees.DataSource = GetData("", "");
        gvEmployees.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void OnFilter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text);
    DateTime toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text);
    gvEmployees.DataSource = GetData(fromDate.ToString(), toDate.ToString());
    gvEmployees.DataBind();
}

private DataTable GetData(string fromDate, string toDate)
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromDate) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(toDate))
    {
        query += "WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN @From AND @To";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From", fromDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", toDate);
    }
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                sda.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
}


Not at all clear why you have some introduction of a repeater. I suggest you dump that.
Drop in 2 textboxes (with TextMode = date, and that will give you a date picker without any extra efforts on your part).
After the 2 textboxes (and our search button), then just add your GridView.
Hence, this markup:
        <h3>Search Hotel Bookings</h3>

        <div style="float: left">
            <h4>Enter start date</h4>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"
                TextMode="Date">
            </asp:TextBox>
        </div>

        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 30px">
            <h4>Enter start date</h4>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server"
                TextMode="Date">
            </asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server"
            Style="float: left; margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 20px"
            Text="Search Bookings"
            CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdSearch_Click" />

        <%--        Start a new line--%>

        <div style="clear: both; height: 10px"></div>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
            CssClass="table table-hover"
            Width="50%"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BookingDate"
                    HeaderText="Booking Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}"
                    ItemStyle-Width="110px" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

And our code behind can be this:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // optinal load all of grid on first page load
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL =
            "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ";

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL); 
        if (txtStartDate.Text.Trim().Length > 0 
            & txtStartDate.Text.Trim().Length > 0 )
        {
            cmdSQL.CommandText += "WHERE BookingDate BETWEEN @Start AND @End ";
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Start", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtStartDate.Text;
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@End", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtEndDate.Text;
        }
        cmdSQL.CommandText += "ORDER BY BookingDate ";
        GridView1.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid();

    }

    public DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }

In fact, I suggest moving the MyRstP "helper" routing to a global static class, as then you not have to write such code over and over.
The end result is thus:
First, we select the start and end date:

Then we hit the search button

Edit: additional using directives
My using directives were:
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

So, nothing beyond what a typical page with SQL queries would require.

The reason for the Repeater is due to a code template that has to be followed but I will forgo it at your advice. I've tested the solution and haven't seen any errors thrown from it though it is an empty database.

did you include any additional directives (using system.****). The solution worked?

Well, as the screen video/capture shows, yes, the posted code works just fine. I mean, it quite simple code, and nothing special is required to make this code work. We of course assume you have a valid working connection to SQL server (create one in the project settings page). Other then you ensuring you have a valid connection to SQL server, then this approach is workable.

Edit: see my edit - I show the 3 using directives I had on that page. Of course the GridView looks rather nice, since I used the CssClass="table" which is a bootstrap class, and they really do make the GV look nice

Okay. My view is not GridView but the approach you used was what I replicated. I have had a hard time getting it to work on aspx.cs side as it keep throwing errors but should just be programmer error on my part. The web application is also empty which isn't very valuable for testing so I will just have to wait and see.

How can your view not be a GridView when your posted markup shows a GridView?

I had to change from GridView to meet new requirements. I thought I could just use your approach in similar fashion.

Then state that you decided to change from using a GridView - else everyone here going to be confused.  And the same approach will work regardless of using a GridView. The code returns a table based on the date filter,  and thus it don't matter what you do with that table (such as sending (binding) to a repeater,  GridView,  ListView or whatever). So once you have the datatable object of filtered data,  then anything that follows should work. Hence yes,  this approach should apply to your use case.
